# get week number of a date

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

```
SELECT strftime('%W', day) AS week, sum(amount) FROM MyTable GROUP BY week ORDER BY week DESC
```

This query is useful to get the amount by week. But this one gives week number in year, May I know how to get week number in month. I have googled lot. But all results are related to week number in year not in month.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: will you count a part of the week as a week, or will you start counting from the first monday in the week?

Comment: @IsmetAlkan I am really sorry about this friend. I dont know. My day in query is like "04-05-2013". The query returns week number as 17.

Comment: then need to Implement Logic to Parse the Week Number in Year to Week Number in Month

Comment: @AkshayJoy May I know how to parse it friend.

Comment: I have added the Answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manipulate strftime() to get your answer.

Apply strftime() on given date and FIRST date of given dates month and subtract them to get your week number of month

Eg

```
 SELECT  strftime('%W','2013-05-04')-strftime('%W','2013-05-01') +1;
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/0c8c7/13)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code

Create A Calendar Instance from the Sqlite date parts

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();


  now.set(Calendar.YEAR,2013);
  now.set(Calendar.MONTH,04);//0- january ..4-May
  now.set(Calendar.DATE, 04);

System.out.println("Current week of month is : " +
            now.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH));

System.out.println("Current week of year is : " +
            now.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
```

Comment: I am not asking this friend. I am asking about how to get week of month in select query. `SELECT strftime('%W', day)` in this part friend.

Comment: Hey Why can't you Parse after sqlite Query... from the Sqlite you can't . Taht why am using Core Java code to achieve the functionality.